# Call to getUserIdentityTokenAsync() returning a null token

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We have an add-in in production where, for certain users, the call to `getUserIdentityTokenAsync()` fails and returns a `null` token.

The response is

```
"Status" = "failed", 
"Error" = {message: "An internal error has occurred", name: "Internal Error"}
```

Would anyone know what could cause this type of failure? Certain users always get the error, and we have never seen the error locally or during development.

It seems to happen only for desktop Outlook users. We have not seen any errors for users when using the add-in via the browser.

Comment: When you say "certain users", is there any commonality between them? For example, is it every user on one Exchange tenant but none on another?

Comment: It does appear to be every user on a particular Exchange tenant. We are currently logging the `hostVersion` for these API calls. Is there additional information we can log from the API to help narrow the possibilities?

Comment: Is it possible the Exchange Server in question doesn't have Exchange Web Services (EWS) enabled and exposed to the internet?

Comment: It is possible. We know they are connected to the internet or our logging would not have tracked the errors. Maybe their firewall is causing an issue as well? I will reach out to them and see if EWS is enabled.

Comment: There have been some issues with getUserIdentityToken in certain versions of desktop Outlook. But the current versions of all versions of Outlook, should have fixes for them now. Specifically, if you were making makeEwsRequest and GetUserIdentityToken calls at the same time, one would fail. Also if you were on MSI Outlook 2016 (not C2R), and connecting against Exchange 2013 (not 2016), there were a few builds where getUserIdentityToken failed. Updates to all clients should pick up the fixes. If you can provide your version numbers, we can check to see if you were hitting those versions.

Comment: However, we have seen this issue intermittently as well, even with the fixes. An error like this, usually means Outlook could not contact the server to get the Token. We have not been able to repro it locally. Any information you have as the commonality of the bugger users, would help us greatly in figuring out the root cause.

Comment: Updating with version numbers of known fixed issues. In MSI versions: 16.0.4540.1000 to 16.0.4585.1000 against Exchange 2013, GetUserIdentityToken did not work. In MSI versions before, 16.0.4540.1000 / 15.0.4931.1000 and C2R versions before 16.0.7813.1000 - calling GetUserIdentityTokenAsync along with MakeEwsRequestAsync would cause a failure.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Today we have received errors from versions 15.0.4569.1503, 15.0.4919.1001,16.0.4573.1001 and 16.0.4588.1000. All of those fall within the versions you mentioned except for 16.0.4588.1000. Most of the time the errors come from within the 16.0.4540.1000 to 16.0.4585.1000 range. We have seen one error with version 16.0.8326.2096.

Comment: I would be happy to provide any information you think could be helpful in determining a cause. The only commonality I could find in the users having problems are falling within the version numbers you specified, so it looks like we have an answer for those cases. As for the errors we receive outside those version numbers, is there anything else we can log from the API that would be useful?

Comment: In general logging the full response like you are doing is helpful. Please keep doing that. In this case, the response does not include an error code or helpful information and we are looking into improving the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am updating the answer based on a response from the Outlook Add-ins Team in the comments.

> In MSI versions: 16.0.4540.1000 to 16.0.4585.1000 against Exchange 2013, GetUserIdentityToken did not work. In MSI versions before, 16.0.4540.1000 / 15.0.4931.1000 and C2R versions before 16.0.7813.1000 - calling GetUserIdentityTokenAsync along with MakeEwsRequestAsync would cause a failure

In my case, most of the users experiencing the problems had the client version numbers posted above. Upgrading their outlook version solved the issue.